# Symfony command - getting data of processed data from service (event listener?)

Tags: php, symfony

I cannot get it. Maybe I don't understand something.
Let's say I want to make cron job which runs ExampleCommand that invokes some service.
I can have tons of data inside and I want to see some progress bar from Command line.

I thought it would be easy using Event Listeners.

My Event:

```
namespace App\Events;
use \Symfony\Contracts\EventDispatcher\Event;

class ExampleEvent extends Event
{
    const NAME = 'example.event';
    protected $msg;

    public function __construct(String $msg)
    {
        $this->msg = $msg;
    }

    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->msg;
    }

}
```

Command:

```
class ExampleCommand extends \Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:example';
    protected $downloader;
    protected $container;
    protected $dispatcher;

    public function __construct(string $name = null, ExampleDownloader $downloader, ContainerInterface $container, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher)
    {
        $this->downloader = $downloader;
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();

        //$this->dispatcher->addSubscriber(new ExampleListener());

        parent::__construct($name);
    }

    protected function configure(): void
    {
        $this->addArgument('filename', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Optional filename');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $this->dispatcher->addListener(ExampleEvent::NAME, function( ExampleEvent $event) use ($output){
            $output->writeln('Z eventu: '.$event->getMessage());
        }, 255);
        $this->downloader->download($input->getArgument('filename'));



        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
```

And a service:

```
class ExampleSaver
{
    protected $dispatcher;


    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher)
    {
        $this->dispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
    }

    public function loadResource(String $resource)
    {
        $this->resource = $resource;
        //$dispatcher->addListener(ExampleEvent::NAME, array(new ExampleListener(), 'onGtfsEvent'));
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(new ExampleEvent('Dupa'), ExampleEvent::NAME);

        echo "koniec";
        $this->checkUnq();
    }
```

I've also tried with own Listener class:

```
class ExampleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $output;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->output = $output;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return ['onExampleEvent' => 'onExampleEvent'];
    }

    public function onExampleEvent(ExampleEvent $event)
    {
        echo 'TERAZ WIDZE: '.$event->getMessage();
        //$this->output->writeln('OUTPUT: '.$event->getMessage());
    }
}
```

using addSubscriber in Command. Unfortunately both - addListener and addSubscriber not working.
After dispatch from service I've got no data in Command.

What I'm doing wrong? Should custom event (or it's name) or listener be configured in services? I don't get it :(

Comment: IIRC You cannot add event listeners / subscribers on runtime

Comment: Start by asking yourself how the newly created EventDispatcher instance is supposed to be injected into your ExampleSaver service.  And as an unrelated suggestion, just use the ExampleEvent classname as the event name.  No need to fool around with ::NAME stuff.

Comment: @FabienPapet You recalled incorrectly.